How do you solve the analogy 369 : 329 :: 237 :?
I came across the following analogy and I’m having trouble identifying the pattern:
369 : 329 :: 237 : ?
I’ve noticed that the numbers on the left and right side of the colon appear to be related, and I need help figuring out the logic or pattern that connects them.
What I've tried:

I first checked the difference between 369 and 329, which is 40. So I thought of subtracting 40 from 237, but that gives me 197, which isn't one of the answer options.
I also considered squaring the digits of the numbers, but I'm not sure how to apply that to find the correct answer.

The options for the missing number are:

169
196
149
100

Could someone please explain how to solve this analogy and help me understand the pattern behind it?

This is a problem in mind-reading, not in mathematics.

In between 329 :: 237 there is a double colon instead of a single one, like 369 : 329 . Is that a typo, or is it supposed to be different?

Yes, because 369 and 329 are related in some way, so you have to find the same number  which is related to 237 ( just like how 329 is related to 369), thus the double colon.

I am sorry but how is this related to mind reading?

Because you must read the mind of they who posed the question. There is no mathematical answer.

I’m voting to close this question because it is completely subjective.

I don't think the question is that deep, it would definitely have some logic so it matches the options.

This is what's known as a four-part analogy or proportional analogy. The study of such analogies certainly has mathematical content, but finding the solution of one particular analogy is more an interesting puzzle than a mathematical problem of the sort normally asked on this site. Maybe the puzzling stack exchange will be more receptive?

Oh alright, will ask the question there.

@randomuser Gerry's and Malady's point isn't that the answer involves no logic or even rationality, but that there are theoretically infinitely many possible answers to such questions.

The question has been posted to puzzling, https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/129290/how-do-you-solve-the-analogy-369-329-237 and has been closed there for lacking proper attribution, as explained at https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide (this is somewhat like our "lacking context" reason for closing here at mathstack). There is something to be said for adopting some of their wording here.
